# How to translate byte received from serial port to hexadecimal?

Tags: java, serialization, serial-port, hex, arrays

i need to read serial port for my sensor board and i use this [example](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port) to read data coming.
but i surprised that the output data on console terminal look like this

```
Wÿðÿ8Ã?íÈÓÿ
```

because i use this `System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));`

this method just print the data each time its receive packet.

but when i used this method for hexa digit the output will write zeros before it receive any data !!

this method

```
    byte[] arr = { 0x00, 0x01 };
    ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr); // big-endian by default
    short  num = wrapped.getShort();
    String f=String.valueOf(num);
    System.out.print(f);
```

So how to deal with this issue to translate incoming bytes to readable data in hexa !!!

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with printing hex. You need something much simpler. Try `Integer.toString(b & 0xFF, 16)` where `b` is an individual byte.

Comment: This code `new String(buffer,0,len)` converts the buffer to a `String` using platform default encoding - this is why you are getting gibberish.

Comment: @bmorris591 how to do that ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, to get each time the individual byte by use 
buffer[len] ??

Comment: I assume you have a byte array, so iterate over all the bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
final byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 }; // or whatever your byte array is
final String asHexStr = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(arr)
System.out.println(asHexStr);
```

Comment: why output write zeros before it receive any data ?

Comment: @Hana90 - not sure I follow you. Are you asking ***why*** you have to output zeros before you can write any data. Or stating that when you print data it is being preceded by zeros?

Comment: well, when i used the link in my question which use System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));

the data will appeared each time when port received data.

but when i use another method to print the bytes, i have zeros at output side before any received for data !!

Comment: it is related to the way of printing bytes ?

Comment: @Hana90 - no, its not possible that the way you print the output changes the behavior of `inputStream.read`. In all likelihood you are getting data from the stream but its not being formatted out correctly.

Comment: what do you think for the two answers here yours and above ?
i try both, i surprised that they give different values ??

yours there are some data appeared in hex (F,E ...ect)
but the answer above always give me decimal without any hexa char ???

Comment: @Hana90 - theres only one other answer that I see. It has some problems - 1) unnecessarily creating a ByteBuffer 2) Iterating the buffer and printing its contents out one byte at a time 3) The format should be "%02X", in order to print out content like '0001', instead of just '01'. Overall, using DatatypeConverter is better because its logic thats already implemented and just works. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize existing interfaces to their full potential. Consider using `printf`.

```
byte[] arr = { 0x00, 0x01 };
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr); // big-endian by default
boolean read = true;
while(read)
  try { System.out.printf("%x",wrapped.get()); } //get each byte, print as hex
  catch(BufferUnderflowException ex) { read = false; } //stop at empty buffer
}
```